# Object is null or not an Object in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following lines of code:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
var searchLink = aToolLinks[ui.item.tool];
var params = "";
if (ui.item.id && ui.item.id != "") {
if (ui.item.tool == "FUN") {
params = "ID_INSTRUMENT=" + ui.item.id;
} else {
params = "ID_NOTATION=" + ui.item.id;
}
} else if (ui.item.isin && ui.item.isin != "") {
params = "isin=" + ui.item.isin;
}
if (ui.item.tool && ui.item.tool == "NEW") {
params = "searchString=" + ui.item.term;
}
if (params != "") {
console.log("URL " + searchLink+"&"+params);
window.location.href = searchLink+"&"+params;
```

In Internet Explorer 8, i get the error:
item.tool is NULL or is not an object

Does somebody know how I can solve?

Thank you!

Comment: The language is JavaScript. jQuery is an API built on and for use with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code in here, but if jQuery is relevant then please specify the jQuery version you're using, and the names/versions of any jquery plugins that might be relevant as well.

Comment: It is JavaScript, my mistake. I need to see why in IE8 i get this Browser error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a tip and try it if resolves your issue

```
Start Internet Explorer then:
1. Press the F12 key (Tools, Developer Tools)
2. Hold Down the key "Ctrl" then "R" (Cache, Clear Browser Cache)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem when my lists have a trailing comma. I think IE8 chokes on them.

I get the error here in IE 8:

```
var l = [{id:1, val:"foo"}, {id:2, val:"bar"},];
    for(var i =0; i < l.length; i++){
        l[i].val;
}
```

if I remove that last comma I don't get the error in IE 8

```
var l = [{id:1, val:"foo"}, {id:2, val:"bar"}];
    for(var i =0; i < l.length; i++){
        l[i].val;
}
```

If `ui` is a literal list in your question, then that might be the cause.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old but in case someone goes through the same issue again... 
For my case the problem that initiated the error was actually an array out of bounds problem. I was trying to access an index that was not populated in the array, or in your case the map or object. In other words it may mean that `tool` is not a valid key in `ui.item`.